# Angular how to fix emit is not a function with Event-emitter

Tags: angular, angular-event-emitter

I'm trying to bind and @Output with a click event with an event emitter to log the data in from a different component.
I would need some guideline I think maybe not using the good approach

[image]

***contactform.component.html***

```
 <form class="form-signin form" [formGroup]="kForm" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit($event)">

    <div class="form-label-group">
      <input type="email" id="inputName"  placeholder="Name" formControlName="name" #name>
      <label for="inputName">Name</label>
    </div> 

    <div class="form-label-group">
      <input type="email"  placeholder="Email address" formControlName="email" #email>
      <label for="inputEmail">Email address</label>
    </div>

    <div class="form-label-group">
      <input type="text"  class="form-control" placeholder="phone" formControlName="phone" #phone>
      <label for="inputPhone">Phone</label>
    </div>

    <div class="form-label-group">
        <input type="text"   placeholder="country" formControlName="country" #country>
        <label for="inputCountry">Country</label>
      </div>

    <button class="btn  btn-primary" type="submit" [disabled]="!kForm.valid" (click)="onSubmit(name.value, email.value, phone.value, country.value)">Submit</button>
</form>
```

***contactform.component.ts***

```
import { Component, OnInit, Output, Input , EventEmitter} from '@angular/core';
import { Contact  } from '../model';

 @Output() onSave =  new EventEmitter<Contact>();  

onSubmit(value:Contact){ 
    this.onSave.emit(value) 
    this.onSave = this.kForm.value;
    // console.log('k',this.kForm.value);
    console.log('submitted', this.onSave)
  }
```

***app.component.html***

```
<contact-form (newItem)="addItem($event)"></contact-form>
```

***app.component.ts***

```
addItem(newItem:string){
    console.log(newItem)
  }
```

***Model.ts***

```
export interface Contact{
    name: string;
    email: string;
    phone: string;
    country: string;

}
```

Comment: just remove this.onSave = this.klloydForm.value, and in a line above this.onSave.emit(this.klloydForm.value), i guess it helps

Comment: @NavruzbekNoraliev that's true Great, but I can get the user inputs in the console

Comment: console.log(value); console.log(this.klloydForm.value)

Comment: that's very true I got myself tricked, great work :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on your provided code, it looks like you are re-assigning your EventEmitter here;

```
onSubmit(value:Contact){ 
    this.onSave.emit(value) 
    this.onSave = this.klloydForm.value; <-------------------- Remove this
    console.log('submitted', this.klloydForm.value)
}
```

If you re-assign this variable, you will lose scope to the original EventEmitter next time the form is submitted.

Comment: Great, I have done and the error is no more showing but the inputs are not logging to the console. can you help with it

Comment: Try adding; console.log('submitted', this.klloydForm.value)

Answer (score 1):

You have created output event which is onSave in contactform.component.ts,so you have to call same event from component to trigger like

```html
<contact-form (onSave)="addItem($event)"></contact-form>
```